# Using .NET Framework 3.5 in a SQL Server 2005 Stored Procedure

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, .net-3.5, stored-procedures, clr

I have an SQL Server 2005 server, and I'd like to run a .Net CLR stored procedure on it. However, I'd like to use .NET Framework 3.5.

If I try this right now, I get this error:

```
Error: Assembly 'system.core, version=3.5.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.' was not found in the SQL catalog.
```

I'm told this is possible in SQL Server 2008, because SQL Server 2008 ships with .NET Framework 3.5. However, I'm wondering if there's a way to add .NET Framework 3.5 to my SQL Server 2005 installation, so that I can run .NET 3.5 stored procedures on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a stupid question but... If system.core can't be found, do you have the framework 3.5 installed on the database server?

Comment: Well, I don't actually have access to check...I figured I'd ask before putting in a request.

Is it really just as simple as installing the .net 3.5 runtime?

Comment: That would be a minimum requirement. How did you expect it to work if 3.5 wasn't installed?

Answer (score 2):

The result of google + trial & error

```
EXEC dbo.sp_changedbowner @loginame = N'sa', @map = true
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
GO
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Core]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 
'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO
```

**Sites**:

- [playing with sql server clr integration part iv deploying to sql server 2005](http://weblogs.asp.net/paulomorgado/archive/2009/06/13/playing-with-sql-server-clr-integration-part-iv-deploying-to-sql-server-2005.aspx)
- [The-database-owner-SID-recorded-in-the-master-database-differs-from-the-database-owner-SID-recorded-in-database-DatabaseName](http://blog.scoftware.com/post/2009/06/05/The-database-owner-SID-recorded-in-the-master-database-differs-from-the-database-owner-SID-recorded-in-database-DatabaseName.aspx)

Comment: ```ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON``` There is no need to use this line and also it may cause security issues.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://forums.microsoft.com/technet/showpost.aspx?postid=2639225&siteid=17) might be helpful to you.